# Initializing the database using java in spring-boot and jpa

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

I am using spring-boot CommandLineRunner class to initialize the database with some initial data which is need for application to run. The problem is that the commandLineRunner class runs everytime application is restarted which creates duplicate entries in the database (when I set hbm2ddl-auto = update).
**How can I make application run initializing statements only once and future deployments should not execute intializing statements which leads to data duplication.**
I could use schema.sql and data.sql files but the initializing data needs to have relational mapping and I am not sure how to do that.
The example records from commandline runner is as follows:

```
    Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class DataLoader
    implements CommandLineRunner {
    
     @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
    
    Role userRole = new Role();
        userRole.setRoleName("user");
        userRole.setDescription("test user");
        roleRepository.save(userRole);
        
        
        //Users and there roles
        User user = new User();
        user.setFirstName("UserFirstName");
        user.setLastName("UserLastName");
        user.setPhoneNumber("xx-232323232323");
        user.addRoleToUser(userRole);
        userRepository.save(user);
        }}
```

Comment: Read about flyway

Comment: You could test if the userRole exists with roleRepository.getRoleByName("user") and jump over the db population if it does exist. There are other, much more sophisticated ways, eg liquibase, but that's a bit of an exercise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could test if the userRole exists with `roleRepository.getRoleByName("user")` and jump over the db population if it does exist. There are other, much more sophisticated ways, eg liquibase, but that's a bit of an exercise.

Suggested implementation:

```
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class DataLoader
    implements CommandLineRunner {
    
     @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
    if(roleRepository.getRoleByName("user").empty()) {
    Role userRole = new Role();
        userRole.setRoleName("user");
        userRole.setDescription("test user");
        roleRepository.save(userRole);
        
        
        //Users and there roles
        User user = new User();
        user.setFirstName("UserFirstName");
        user.setLastName("UserLastName");
        user.setPhoneNumber("xx-232323232323");
        user.addRoleToUser(userRole);
        userRepository.save(user);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How to skip in commandlineRunner class run() method

Comment: Added suggested implementation to answer

Answer (score 0):

You can check if those specific role and user exist or not before insertion.